# Trying to use regsvr32 registered DLLs in VS 2019

Tags: c++, dll, regsvr32, visual-studio-2019

So here's the issue:

I have an old software system written in C++ and built originally on Win Xp with VS 2005 SP1. Most of the solutions in this code-base are reliant on third-party DLLs that are registered using `regsvr32.exe`. Without this step VS 2005 throws out Linker errors. After registration everything works like a charm.

I've been able to successfully rebuild the project using Win 10 and VS 2005 and now I'm trying to do the same with newer version of VS, namely VS 2019. For a single test solution I was able to resolve compilation errors, but it seems that VS 2019 Linker cannot find DLLs that should have been registered with regsvr32, since I'm getting the same Linker errors that I have have been getting with VS 2005 prior to registering DLLs.

I'm most certainly sure that this is due to VS 2019 "not seeing" DLLs that were registered with regsvr32. Thus the question: does anybody have any idea how to make VS 2019 discover those DLLs?

DLLs and target for compiler are 32bit. I've been using SysWOW64\regsvr for registering 32 bit DLLs. The folder with DLLs is in $PATH. Also the folder with DLLs is set in `Project -> Project Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories` setting of VS 2019

Edit:
Linker Errors in both cases (before using regsvr32 with VS 2005 and with VS 2019) are of form:

```
...
1>RecordSet.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall IDatabase::~IDatabase(void)" (__imp_??1IDatabase@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void * __thiscall IDatabase::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GIDatabase@@QAEPAXI@Z)
...
```

Followed by `fatal error LNK1120: 17 unresolved externals`

I'd be glad to get any pointers.

Comment: Exactly what is the error you are getting? Please add it to the question. (It has been a few years since I did any COM at this level, but my collection is the linker does not use the registered dll – only the lib generated by by the typelib compiler or nothing when using `#import` (the functions are generated inline)).

Comment: The thing that really confuses me is that I got the same erors (to the line) in VS 2005 and they were solved by running couple of `.bat` scripts with a bunch of `regsvr32` calls to a bunch of DLLs. So VS 2005 clearly picked and used them and somehow VS 2019 can't do the same. I know I sound lame, but I feel even more lame)

Comment: Looking at that error it seems the compiler is generating a destructor call. Given the huge changes to C++ support in the 14 years (or so) since VS2005 this might be compiler standards compliance.

Comment: Hm, might as well be that, thanks for your time) I'll get to further investigation